# Swift trouble send request with dynamic field json

Tags: json, swift

I've got simple struct:

```
struct LoginModel: Codable {
var user: String
var password: String
}
```

Fill my model and encode using `JSONEncoder()`. 
Next create URLRequest

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: timeOut)
let headers = [
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
]
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = data
```

run `URLSessionDataTask` with this request from URLSession.shared. 
Beckend gets json with null fields.
But instead I've sent dictionary with fixed filed it's work fine.

```
      let parameters = [
            "user": "user",
            "password": "hash"
            ] 
let data = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
```

When I decode using `JSONDecoder()` back to my model, all variable are filled.
Server side endpoints using other apps written in objc. This app using NSDicionary and NSJSONSerialization and work fine.

How to pass JSON data dynamically.

Comment: show how you create object of your struct and encode it ???

Comment: You might specify the *Accept* header, too.

Comment: @Sh_Khan encode using extension LoginModel
Crate LoginModel by sending unwrapped text from UITextField to struct init

Comment: please share code.............

Comment: @vadian
 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") it try add, but nothing happened

Comment: @Sh_Khan code https://pastebin.com/ZVsJNud2